# Unzip in memory for google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, memory, unzip

I would like to unzip a file uploaded to a servlet, and store all decompressed files to the DataStore as byte[].  Since there is no file system in GAE, I have to put everything in memory.  Suppose I have byte[] allzipdata to store the original zip file data.  How do I unzip the file and especially how to get inputstream from each zipentry which are in memory?

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allzipdata));
ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
while(ze!=null){
}
```

So what's in the while loop?

Also, if I upload a file, I know the contentType using item.getContentType(); in which item is a FileItemStream.  So for a zipentry, is there a way to know the contentType?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read image data from the `ZipInputStream` I'd recommend to use the [Apache Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library. It converts the ZIP entry of the input stream to a byte array:

```java
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allzipdata));
    ZipEntry ze = null;
    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       // write your code to use zip entry e.g. below:
       String filename = ze.getName();
       System.out.println("File Name of Entry file="+fileName);
       byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(zis);
       // now work with the image `data`
    }
```

Comment: There's a typo error fileName var declaration is not having camel notation.